# How to copy text of a WPF textbox in an IAsyncQuickInfoSource tooltip to clipboard

Tags: wpf, vsix

I have a Visual Studio Extension (vsix) with a quick info tooltip (IAsyncQuickInfoSource) that show a textbox (WPF). When you hover the mouse over a keyword it will show some useful info. The content of the textbox is selectable.

I like to copy the content of the textbox with Ctrl+C. However, instead of copying the content of the textbox into clipboard, text from the textbuffer where the quick info tooltip originated is copied.

The [textbox is focusable](https://github.com/HJLebbink/vsix-bug-quickinfosession/blob/master/VsixBug/QuickInfo/BugWindow.xaml). This [minimal example project](https://github.com/HJLebbink/vsix-bug-quickinfosession) shows the undesired behavious.

**Question**: how to copy text of the textbox in my tooltip to clipboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy text to the clipboard you can use `SetContent()` method of `Clipboard` static class.

The issue of the shortcut is a bit more involved though. Main reason is that shortcuts in VS work in scopes so even if you define the same `Ctrl + C` shortcut as shortcut to a command in your extension (e.g. using method described here [How to register key binding code on VSIX package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071825/how-to-register-key-binding-code-on-vsix-package-installation)) the default Editor Copy command will take precedence over yours and will continue to handle that shortcut. Because your shortcut is considered to be Global scope and the Editor has same shortcut in more specific scope.

To make it work you will need to define the shortcut on the scope of your tool window specifically. This way when your window is focused, VS will give precedence to the scope of your tool window rather than the editor invoking your shortcut as a result.
There are few steps involved in the process you can refer to this answer to see how one developer did it https://stackoverflow.com/a/42899788/633495

An alternative you can consider is to add a small button to your tool window to copy the content without needing to have a shortcut.